# Is $ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{2p_i^3})} $ equivalent to this sum of partitions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, integer-partitions

$$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{2 p_i^3})} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2} ; \frac{1}{2})_k \: \frac{Par(n-\Omega(k+1)+k, k)}{(k+1)^3} $$

where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime and $ \Omega(n), (x;x)_k , Par(n,k) $ are the [Prime Omega function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function), [Q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol), and the [Partition Triangle](https://oeis.org/A008284), respectively.

This is only conjectured and Mathematica gives a value of $1.0937396 \dots$ for both.

Edit: Expanding the LHS yields $$ \frac{\zeta^{\frac{1}{2}}(3)}{{\zeta^{\frac{1}{8}}(6)}\zeta^{\frac{1}{8}}(9) \zeta^{\frac{3}{64}}(12) \zeta^{\frac{3}{32}}(15) } \cdots $$ though I'm not sure if that helps working out the RHS.